# SQL Query to sort date based on two column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following data in table `RATING` and i want to sort this based on Rating and Year.

Database MS SQL Server

Unsorted data in Table

```
ID  PlayerName  Rating  Year    
1   A   8   2022    
2   B   8   2022
3   C   0   2022
4   A   7   2020
5   B   6   2020
6   C   6   2020
7   E   5   2020
8   D   5   2020
9   D   5   2022
```

Data should show as below

```
ID  PlayerName  Rating  Year
1   A   8   2022
2   B   8   2022
3   D   5   2022
9   C   0   2022
4   A   7   2020
5   B   6   2020
6   C   6   2020
7   E   5   2020
8   D   5   2020
```

I am not able to get it right i used following Query

```
SELECT ID, PlayerName, Rating, Year 
FROM   RATING 
Where Year IN (SELECT Year from Rating) 
order by year DESC
```

but it doesn't get the correct order as i am not able to use order by clause in sub query as it generates error `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.`

Event two column sort is not working properly

```
SELECT ID, PlayerName, Rating, Year 
FROM   RATING 
order by Rating, Year
```

Comment: Why does your WHERE statement look like that? that doesn't seem to be doing anything. What error do you get from `ORDER BY RATING, YEAR` because that seems correct so I'm wondering why that would not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to `ORDER BY` year DESC first then `Rating` DESC

```
SELECT ID, PlayerName, Rating, [Year] 
FROM RATING 
order by [Year] DESC,Rating DESC
```

`Year` is a keyword in sqlserver, I would use brackets to contain it.

Comment: So you mean to say Query is fine but year being a Keyword is creating problems.. I did warp [year] in Select part in my sql and not in order by.. Sometime small things or basic thing breaks simple query.. Thanks for explanation

Comment: @student Yes `Year` is a function if you want to use that for a column name, we might use `[]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is not bad so far. But there are two things you need to change.
First: The column with the higher priority for your sorting is the column "year", so this has to be used first, and then the column "rating".
Second: You must add the key word "DESC" to begin with the newest year and the highest ranking.
So your query should be this one:

```
SELECT * FROM rating ORDER BY year DESC, rating DESC;
```

You can see this is working here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5d55e41464bfbcc1373ba24606cc5ab)

If you can rename the columns on your DB, I recommend to do not use SQL key words as column names (in your example, this the column "year") and to do not use column names that are identic to the table names (in your case, you could rename the table "rating" to "ratings" or similar).
Both of this is of course possible, but could sometimes be bad to read and let increase the risk of issues.

Comment: why does it show different result when i switch columns in order by clause `SELECT * FROM rating ORDER BY rating DESC, year DESC;` as i was using this query and result is different logically it should be same Fiddle updated https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd79e171b6ed99ca1b380a7ad68e6a31

Comment: In this case, it is sorting by rating with higher priority and by year as second. Meaning it is sorted by rating first without checking the year and only those entries having the same rating will then be sorted by year.

Comment: I understood now what was causing issue, i did wrap [Year] in select part while testing but not the order by part of the query... appreciate your help